# MYSQL get latest date

Tags: mysql

i have query like this

```
SELECT seq, idtransaction, tanggal, tmptanggal, tgljatuhtempo,  
@kodeku:=kodetb as kodetb, memberid, namadepan, namabelakang, tipekartu,nokk, 
namabank, cf_1095, gesekan, amount, @ha:=if (seq=1, tmpkuranggesek-amount,@ha-
amount) as kuranggesek   from
( SELECT 
 IFNULL(@subject,@subject := vtiger_servicecontracts.subject), IF(@subject <> 
vtiger_servicecontracts.subject, @sec := 1, @sec := @sec+1) , @sec AS seq,
 IF(@subject <> vtiger_servicecontracts.subject, @subject := 
vtiger_servicecontracts.subject, ''), 
DATE_FORMAT(paymentdate ,'%d/%m/%Y') as tanggal, 
 DATE_FORMAT(due_date ,'%d/%m/%Y') as tgljatuhtempo, tmp.tanggal as tmptanggal,
tmp.kuranggesek as tmpkuranggesek,idtransaction,
 vtiger_servicecontracts.subject as kodetb, @amount:=amount as amount,
 vtiger_servicecontracts.subject as subject, vtiger_contactdetails.contactid as memberid, campaignname as nokk, vtiger_contactdetails.firstname as namadepan, vtiger_contactdetails.lastname as namabelakang, vtiger_leaddetails.lastname as tipekartu, cf_1085 as namabank,cf_1095, amount as gesekan, @ha:=@ha-amount FROM `vtiger_accounting_payments`, vtiger_accounting ,vtiger_servicecontracts,vtiger_servicecontractscf, vtiger_vendorcf, vtiger_crmentity,vtiger_user2role, vtiger_role, vtiger_users,vtiger_leaddetails, vtiger_contactdetails, vtiger_campaign, (select @sec := 0, @subject := null    
) sel,  temp_kuranggesek_stafsda tmp 
WHERE vtiger_crmentity.crmid=vtiger_accounting_payments.idtransaction 
and vtiger_servicecontracts.subject=tmp.kodetb
and vtiger_accounting_payments.machinename=vtiger_vendorcf.cf_1077
and vtiger_accounting.accountingrelated2=vtiger_servicecontracts.servicecontractsid      and vtiger_servicecontractscf.servicecontractsid=vtiger_servicecontracts.servicecontractsid and accountingtype='Pelunasan Gesek' and 
vtiger_accounting_payments.idtransaction=vtiger_accounting.accountingid and 
vtiger_crmentity.deleted=0 and vtiger_user2role.userid=vtiger_users.id and 
vtiger_crmentity.smcreatorid=vtiger_user2role.userid and   
vtiger_user2role.roleid=vtiger_role.roleid and vtiger_users.user_name='staff' and cf_1091=leadid and  
vtiger_contactdetails.contactid=vtiger_servicecontracts.contactid and 
vtiger_campaign.campaignid=cf_1155 and date_format(paymentdate,'%Y-%m-%d') = date_format('2016-03-14','%Y-%m-%d') order by vtiger_servicecontracts.subject 
)     
AS temp
```

this query works successfully when table of tmp_kuranggesek_stafsda have data like this:

```
tanggal      kodetb    kuranggesek
10-03-2016   1         600
11-03-2016   2         550
```

but when one kodetb have two dates, such below:

```
tanggal      kodetb    kuranggesek
10-03-2016   1         600
11-03-2016   2         550
11-03-2016   2         100
```

query will repeat displaying data as column tanggal because kodetb "2" has 2 dates.

my question is:

how to make this query can select only 1 date from table temp_kuranggesek_stafsda which  has the latest date of selected kodetb?

Comment: Which value of `kuranggesek` (whatever that means) do you want to retain in the event of multiple records for a given date?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [aggregate function](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-functions.html) . you should use `MAX()` like

```
SELECT MAX(tanggal),kodetb, kuranggesek 
FROM table_name
GROUP BY kodetb;
```

Your query is lenghty so i read only question. According to your requirment you should use aggregate function.

```
SELECT MAX(tanggal),kodetb, kuranggesek 
FROM (
SELECT seq, idtransaction, tanggal, tmptanggal, tgljatuhtempo,  
@kodeku:=kodetb as kodetb, memberid, namadepan, namabelakang, tipekartu,nokk, 
namabank, cf_1095, gesekan, amount, @ha:=if (seq=1, tmpkuranggesek-amount,@ha-
amount) as kuranggesek   from
( SELECT 
 IFNULL(@subject,@subject := vtiger_servicecontracts.subject), IF(@subject <> 
vtiger_servicecontracts.subject, @sec := 1, @sec := @sec+1) , @sec AS seq,
 IF(@subject <> vtiger_servicecontracts.subject, @subject := 
vtiger_servicecontracts.subject, ''), 
DATE_FORMAT(paymentdate ,'%d/%m/%Y') as tanggal, 
 DATE_FORMAT(due_date ,'%d/%m/%Y') as tgljatuhtempo, tmp.tanggal as tmptanggal,
tmp.kuranggesek as tmpkuranggesek,idtransaction,
 vtiger_servicecontracts.subject as kodetb, @amount:=amount as amount,
 vtiger_servicecontracts.subject as subject, vtiger_contactdetails.contactid as memberid, campaignname as nokk, vtiger_contactdetails.firstname as namadepan, vtiger_contactdetails.lastname as namabelakang, vtiger_leaddetails.lastname as tipekartu, cf_1085 as namabank,cf_1095, amount as gesekan, @ha:=@ha-amount FROM `vtiger_accounting_payments`, vtiger_accounting ,vtiger_servicecontracts,vtiger_servicecontractscf, vtiger_vendorcf, vtiger_crmentity,vtiger_user2role, vtiger_role, vtiger_users,vtiger_leaddetails, vtiger_contactdetails, vtiger_campaign, (select @sec := 0, @subject := null    
) sel,  temp_kuranggesek_stafsda tmp 
WHERE vtiger_crmentity.crmid=vtiger_accounting_payments.idtransaction 
and vtiger_servicecontracts.subject=tmp.kodetb
and vtiger_accounting_payments.machinename=vtiger_vendorcf.cf_1077
and vtiger_accounting.accountingrelated2=vtiger_servicecontracts.servicecontractsid      and vtiger_servicecontractscf.servicecontractsid=vtiger_servicecontracts.servicecontractsid and accountingtype='Pelunasan Gesek' and 
vtiger_accounting_payments.idtransaction=vtiger_accounting.accountingid and 
vtiger_crmentity.deleted=0 and vtiger_user2role.userid=vtiger_users.id and 
vtiger_crmentity.smcreatorid=vtiger_user2role.userid and   
vtiger_user2role.roleid=vtiger_role.roleid and vtiger_users.user_name='staff' and cf_1091=leadid and  
vtiger_contactdetails.contactid=vtiger_servicecontracts.contactid and 
vtiger_campaign.campaignid=cf_1155 and date_format(paymentdate,'%Y-%m-%d') = date_format('2016-03-14','%Y-%m-%d') order by vtiger_servicecontracts.subject 
)     
AS temp) AS new_temp 
GROUP BY kodetb;
```

Hope this will work for you.